# Splitting a line in a file into two columns

Tags: awk, sed, files

I want to split a line into two coloumns

```
./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties:app.pass=*****
```

I want the colon(:) in the above line as seperator and output like below

```
./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties                        app.pass
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: The output looks like it's from `grep`, showing both the file name and line.  If all you need is the line, add `-h`.  If all you need is the file, add `-l`.

Comment: directory names can contain `:` or `=` so how would you differentiate the path before the `:` from the text after it? Feels like you're trying to close the barn door after the horse has bolted and you need to address the command generating that output as @Wildcard suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F"[:=]" '{print $1"\t"$2}' $file
```

We set 2 delimiters to `FS` so we can set everything after `=` to a column and exclude it.

You could also use `sed`

```
sed -E 's/(^.*):(.*)=.*/\1\t\2/'
```

**Output***

```
./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties     app.pass
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
echo "./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties:app.pass=*****" | tr ':' '\t'
```

Comment: That doesn't address the trailing `=*****`.

Answer (score 1):

Also using `awk` this possibility:

```
echo './ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties:app.pass=*****' | awk 'sub(/=[^=]*$/,""){sub(/:/,"\t")} 1'
./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties     app.pass
```

- `sub()` returns 1 if the substitution is successful; 0 otherwise.
- condition: first `sub()` function. Is there replacement? if yes, then the action, i.e. the second `sub()` function.
- first `sub()`: `sub(/=[^=]*$/,"")` removes from `=` to the end.
- second `sub()`: `sub(/:/,"\t")` replaces `:` for tab `\t`

Comment: I don;;t think deleting lines that don't contain `=` is desirable.

Comment: Youre welcome. My first comment still stands though - I don't see anything in the question to suggest lines that don't contain `=` should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

If all you want is to split on a single `:` colon:

```perl
raku -ne '.split(":").join("\t").put;'
```

If however, you want to clean up the second element (index=1):

```perl
raku -ne '.=split(":"); put( .[0] ~ "\t" ~ .[1].subst(/ \=.* /));'
```

Sample Input:

```
./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties:app.pass=*****
```

Sample Output (1):

```
./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties    app.pass=*****
```

Sample Output (2):

```
./ABC/dce/app/config/fgh/pqr/app.properties    app.pass
```

Briefly, the `split` routine destructively splits on `:` colon, removing it. In the first example, the resultant strings are joined back together with `\t` tab. In the second example, the resultant strings are actually saved back into the `$_` topic variable using the `.=` assignment operator, so a second operation can be performed (`.=` is shorthand for `$_.=`). The second operation `subst` substitutes the `\=.*` regex with nothing  ( i.e. deleting it).

Note, string concatenation in Raku is accomplished with `~` tilde. The code above accomplishes the requested task--however if you want to change the spacing between columns, you could try string concatenation with something like `~ "\t" xx 4 ~` ( i.e. `\t` tab repeated 4 times).

https://raku.org